# Angular 10 Test: Component Resolver Data Subscription Error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I've spend the last few days trying to get up to speed with `ng test` and all the spec files `@angular/cli` creates when creating components and, well, pretty much else.

As I was working on my own portfolio website, I have come across an issue that I cannot seem to understand or fix.

I have this component (pretty vanilla stuff):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { ProjectDetails } from './project-details'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects-details',
  templateUrl: './projects-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-details.component.sass']
})
export class ProjectsDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  // Class variables
  currentContent: ProjectDetails

  constructor(
    private route : ActivatedRoute,
    private title: Title
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Assign the data to local variable for use
    this.route.data.subscribe(content => {
      this.currentContent = content.project.view //<-- This line causes the issue

      // Set the title for the Projects view
      this.title.setTitle(this.currentContent.view_title)
    })
  }

}
```

And this spec file (more vanilla stuff):

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing'
import { ProjectsDetailsComponent } from './projects-details.component';
import { ProjectDetails } from './project-details'

describe('ProjectsDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: ProjectsDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectsDetailsComponent>;
  const projectDetails : ProjectDetails = { /* valid object content */ }

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ ProjectsDetailsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectsDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.currentContent = projectDetails
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When running the tests, I get this error:

`TypeError: content.project is undefined in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js (line 1576)`

So, I'm not sure exactly what's going on here. No matter what I do, the error prevails.I have a similarly setup component that doesn't have this issue and a side by side comparison shows no differences in the `spec.ts` file aside from imports.

I tried changing the file to this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing'
import { ProjectsDetailsComponent } from './projects-details.component';
import { ProjectDetails } from './project-details'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

describe('ProjectsDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: ProjectsDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectsDetailsComponent>;
  const projectDetails : ProjectDetails = {/* valid content */}

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // imports:[
      //   RouterTestingModule
      // ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: projectDetails }
      ],
      declarations: [ ProjectsDetailsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectsDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.currentContent = projectDetails
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Which changes the error to this (which confuses me more):

`TypeError: this.route.data is undefined in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js (line 1575)`

The question to the community: how do I fix this? What's the reason this error is coming up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of providing the raw `projectDetails`, provide an Observable in its data property:

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';

...        
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
         // Properly provide the activated route mock object.
         { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { data: of(projectDetails) } }
      ],
      declarations: [ ProjectsDetailsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
...
```

If you look at how you access the route data, you can see that it uses an Observable:

```
this.route.data.subscribe(content => {...});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! unfortunately, this has not worked. The error persists.

Comment: Strange. In your test the error is `this.route.data is undefined` which means that you don't provide a value for `this.route.data`. This makes sense, because you directly provide your projectDetails object for ActivatedRoute. If you  add the provider to your test as I specified, it should work. Maybe you have a caching issue when executing the tests?

Comment: Oh, goodness me. This is terribly embarrassing. You know how I said in the file `const projectDetails : ProjectDetails = {/* valid content */}`? Turns out... it wasn't valid. Fixing that object made everything work with your provided answer. *facepalm*